# What would cause a Cocos2d iPhone font to only showing 2/3rds of the letter/number?

Tags: iphone, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use [this font](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font) in a cocos2d iPhone game.  The font only shows 2/3rds of the letter/number.  If I open the text editor installed with OS X and use the font, the letters appear fine.  Any ideas to what may be wrong?

Here's the code snippet showing how I display a string using the font:

```
    CCLabel* number = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"1" fontName:@"digital-7" fontSize:64];
    // position the label on the center of the screen
    number.position =  ccp( 20 , size.height/2);
    number.color = ccc3(0,0,0);

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild: number];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that dimensions needed to be specified for the CCLabel.  The default area must have been too small which caused the text to be clipped.  When I added the dimensions parameter, the text appeared correctly.

`[CCLabel labelWithString:@"1000" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft fontName:@"digital-7 (mono)" fontSize:48];`